# Matrix (MCSC format ) product how to perform?

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm implementing a matrix class in modified compressed sparse column format , I have not idea to how to perform the product , this matrix store all the non zero element in 2 vector (value and index) in particular this format of storing consist of 2 container construct in this way:

- `aa_` the vector of value, stored in is first matrix-dim element the value of the diagonal, and then all the non zero value off-diagonal
- `ja_` stored in it's first matrix-dim element the number of non zero off-diagonal element in this way :`ja[0]=matrix.dimension +1` then `ja_[i] -ja_[i+1] = nnz` element of column `i+1` , and in the `ja[ja_[i]] = index_of_row` of the non zero element.

If you would read something about this format you can look here [Modified compressed format](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mcrob/toolbox/c++/sparseMatrix/sparse_matrix_compression.html)

I've implemented a class but I would figure out how to perform the matrix product, I hope somebody can help me about

```
# include <iosfwd>
# include <initializer_list>
# include <iomanip>
# include <cassert>
# include <cmath>
# include <vector>

template <typename data_type> class MCSCmatrix ;      

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const MCSCmatrix<T>& A ,const std::vector<T>& x)noexcept ;




template <typename data_type>
class MCSCmatrix {

    public:
 template <typename T>
      friend std::vector<T> operator*(const MCSCmatrix<T>& A ,const std::vector<T>& x) noexcept ;

auto constexpr printMCSC() const noexcept ;

  private:  

      std::vector<data_type>     aa_ ;  // non zero value value 

      std::vector<std::size_t>   ja_ ; 

      std::size_t dim ;
};


template <typename T>
inline constexpr MCSCmatrix<T>::MCSCmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> row) 
{
      this->dim = row.size();
      auto il = *(row.begin());

      if(this-> dim != il.size())
      {
            throw InvalidSizeException("Matrix Must be square in Modified CSC format ");
      }

      std::vector<std::vector<T>> temp(row);

      aa_.resize(dim+1);
      ja_.resize(dim+1);

      //std::size_t elemCount = 0;      
      ja_[0] = dim+2 ;
      auto elemCount = 0;
      for(auto c = 0 ; c < temp[0].size() ; c++ )
      {     
            elemCount =0 ;  
            for(auto r = 0  ; r < temp.size() ; r++) 
            {
                  if(c==r)
                  {
                     aa_[c] = temp[r][c] ;   
                  }
                  else if(c != r && temp[r][c] !=0)
                  {     
                      aa_.push_back(temp[r][c]);
                      ja_.push_back(r+1);
                      elemCount++ ;  
                  }
            }
            ja_[c+1] = ja_[c] + elemCount ;
      }
      printMCSC();
}

template <typename T>
inline auto constexpr MCSCmatrix<T>::printMCSC() const noexcept 
{
      std::cout << "aa:  " ;      
      for(auto& x : aa_ ) 
            std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      std::cout << "ja:  " ;      
      for(auto& x : ja_ ) 
            std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;

}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const MCSCmatrix<T>& A ,const std::vector<T>& x) noexcept 
{
      assert(A.dim == x.size());
      std::vector<T> b(x.size());

      for(auto i=0 ; i < A.dim ; i++ )
            b.at(i) = A.aa_.at(i) * x.at(i) ; // diagonal value 

     for(auto i=0; i< A.dim ; i++)
     {
         for(auto k=A.ja_.at(i)-1 ; k < A.ja_.at(i+1)-1 ; k++ )
         {   
              b.at(A.ja_.at(k)-1) += A.aa_.at(k)* x.at(i);
         } 
     }
     return b;
}
```

and here the main function:

```
# include "ModCSCmatrix.H"


using namespace std;


int main(){

    MCSCmatrix<int> m1 =  {{11,12,13,14,0,0},{0,22,23,0,0,0},{0,0,33,34,35,36},{0,0,0,44,45,0},
                           {0,0,0,0,0,56},{0,0,0,0,0,66}};

    m1.printMCSC();

  MCSCmatrix<double> m100  = {{1.01, 0 , 2.34,0}, {0, 4.07, 0,0},{3.12,0,6.08,0},{1.06,0,2.2,9.9} };

  std::vector<double> v1={0,1.3,4.2,0.8};

  std::vector<double> v2 = m100*v1 ;
 for(auto& x : v2)
    cout << x << ' ' ;
  cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to multiply two matrix ?

Comment: yes ! but stored in this format

Comment: so why don't you use armadillo library? It is a handy and useful library and provides many useful features.

Comment: I don't think that in the armadillo library there is this kind of storage format .. and I don't want use to much external library into a computational fluid dynamic code

Comment: do you understood the storage way ?

Comment: You'd better express MCSC format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159693/discussion-between-pouyan-bn-and-drudox-lebowsky).